# Fast Forward,rewind for QAudioOutput

Tags: qt4, qt4.7, qfile, qtmultimedia

Hey am playing an audio file using QAudioOutput I need to implement a slider with which u can seek a track at a particular time.

Comment: and your question is???

Comment: My question was how to seek track from QAudioOutput.

Answer (score 1):

```
QBuffer::pos() & QBuffer::seek()
```